# Check if form inputs are empty and if not, display a hidden div on submit button press

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, input

I have a form that has two inputs, one for text and one for checkbox. What I am trying to do is to check if these input fields are empty. If text input is empty and checkbox not checked, it will display an error message. Otherwise if there are no empty input fields, then the submit button will hide the parent div and show another div displaying the message.

```
<div class="newsletter-register">
    <form action="#" id="" class="newsletter-register-form">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="newsletter" name="newsletter" value="">
            <label for="newsletter" class="newsletter-check-label">I have agreed</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="email"> 
            <label for="email" class="form-email-label"></label>
            <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control form-email" placeholder="your e-mail address">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name='submitform' class="newsletter-join" value="Subscribe">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="newsletter-joined" style="display: none;">     
       <h4>Well done</h4>
 </div>
<div class="error-message" style="display: none;">
    <p>You forgot something.</p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".newsletter-register-form").submit(function() {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.newsletter-joined').css("display","block");
        $('.newsletter-register').css("display","none");
        if($(".form-email").val().length == 0){
            $(".error-message").show();
        result=false;
        }
        if($('.newsletter-check2').prop('checked', false)){
           $(".error-message").show();
        result=false;
        }   
        return result;
    });
});
```

I can't seem to get it work properly as I should. At this current state, submit button refreshes the page.

Comment: What are you trying to return a result to? You can't return values from event callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple, here is a fix.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".newsletter-register-form").submit(function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.newsletter-joined').hide();
    $('.newsletter-register').hide();
    $(".error-message").hide();
    var result = true;
    if ($(".form-email").val().length == 0) { // is empty, note you may think of the text is blank
      result = false;
    } else
    if (!$('.newsletter-check2').prop('checked')) { // not checked
      result = false;
    }

    if (!result)
      $(".error-message").show(); // show error message
    else $('.newsletter-joined').show(); // success
    return result;
  });
});
```

Comment: I really dont know if you are kidding with me or not, please look at the code above and compare before you comment.